# Grails reverse engineering and table/column naming strategy

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, grails, reverse-engineering

I'm quite new to Grails, but I have a strong background with Spring 3 and Hibernate. Actually I'm just playing around with it to see how much I can improve productivity for small-medium sized projects.
I'm trying to migrate a legacy SQLServer-Hibernate-Spring-JSP application to Grails, so that's why I installed the reverse engineering plugin. Although it was easy to get it running, I'm now facing some kind of naming convention/strategy with column names that I don't know how to solve.
I run the plugin to generate the domain class for a single table (just to try) in my SQL Server db, and then run "generate-all" to get the controller and the CRUD views. Everything works fine till this point. When I run the app and the main view showing all available controllers is shown, I click on my new generated controller but that leads me to an error page, which says that a certain column name was not found.
Please see below the domain class generated:

```
class Documentos {

    String fileName
    Integer fileSize
    byte[] document
    Integer idTipoDocumento
    Boolean visible
    Date dateElaborated
    Date dateApproved
    String state
    String author
    String department
    String scope
    String language
    String codeNumber
    String comments
    Boolean manual
    Boolean hasChecklists

    static mapping = {
        id generator: "assigned"
    }

    static constraints = {
        fileName maxSize: 150
        fileSize nullable: true
        document nullable: true
        idTipoDocumento nullable: true
        visible nullable: true
        dateElaborated nullable: true
        dateApproved nullable: true
        state nullable: true
        author nullable: true
        department nullable: true
        scope nullable: true
        language nullable: true
        codeNumber nullable: true
        comments nullable: true
        manual nullable: true
        hasChecklists nullable: true
    }
}
```

If I check the generated class, everything looks fine (except that SQLServer nvarchar types were converted to Serializable instead of String, but I can accept by now applying a manual replace).
However, when Grails calls the list method in `DocumentosController.groovy` the following error is retrieved:

```
Error |
2014-08-06 11:20:30,711 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - El nombre de columna 'code_number' no es válido.
Error |
2014-08-06 11:20:30,718 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SQLServerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /IdeaProjects/documentos/index
El nombre de columna 'code_number' no es válido.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: El nombre de columna 'code_number' no es válido.
    Line | Method
->>  216 | makeFromDatabaseError      in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1515 | getNextResult              in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement
|    404 | doExecutePreparedStatement in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement
|    350 | doExecute                  in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd
|   5696 | execute . . . . . . . . .  in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand
|   1715 | executeCommand             in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection
|    180 | executeCommand . . . . . . in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement
|    155 | executeStatement           in     ''
|    285 | executeQuery . . . . . . . in com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement
|     55 | <init>                     in grails.orm.PagedResultList
|     15 | $tt__index . . . . . . . . in com.DocumentosController
|    200 | doFilter                   in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    886 | runTask                    in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|    908 | run . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
^    662 | run                        in java.lang.Thread
```

Basically, it says that "code_number" column was not found, but as you can see in the domain class, the actual column name is codeNumber. I don't understand why Grails is trying to access a column named "code_number" but I guess it could be something about naming strategy, as I can see in [Grails site](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#customNamingStrategy). I guess that this naming strategy is nice when you're not reverse engineering, but I don't know how to fix it for this particular case. Obviously, I don't want to change all my database column names.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

**EDIT:**

OK, I've been able to solve the problem, although I'm not happy with the soution. I added some explicit mappings to the generated class, and that fixed the issue. The final class should be this one:

```
class Documentos {

    String fileName
    Integer fileSize
    byte[] document
    Integer idTipoDocumento
    Boolean visible
    Date dateElaborated
    Date dateApproved
    String state
    String author
    String department
    String scope
    String language
    String codeNumber
    String version
    String comments
    Boolean manual
    Boolean hasChecklists

    static mapping = {
        id generator: "assigned"
        fileName column: "fileName", sqlType: "varchar", length: 150
        fileSize column: "fileSize", sqlType: "int"
        idTipoDocumento column: "idTipoDocumento", sqlType: "int"
        codeNumber column: "codeNumber", sqlType: "nvarchar", length: 4
        version column: "version", sqlType: "nvarchar", length: 4
        dateApproved column: "dateApproved", sqlType: "smalldatetime"
        dateElaborated column: "dateElaborated", sqlType: "smalldatetime"
        hasChecklists column: "hasChecklists", sqlType: "bit"
    }

    static constraints = {
        fileName maxSize: 150
        fileSize nullable: true
        document nullable: true
        idTipoDocumento nullable: true
        visible nullable: true
        dateElaborated nullable: true
        dateApproved nullable: true
        state nullable: true
        author nullable: true
        department nullable: true
        scope nullable: true
        language nullable: true
        codeNumber nullable: true
        comments nullable: true
        manual nullable: true
        hasChecklists nullable: true
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, this is not what I expect from Grails. I expected to get a working domain class from the reverse engineering process, but instead I get a class which I still need to modify. I don't want to do this for the other 100 tables in my DB....... Does anybody know if there is some kind of configuration I could add to avoid all this "manual" mappings?

Thanks!!

Comment: By default, a domain class property named `codeNumber` will map to a table column named `code_number`. Have you checked that a column named `code_number` exists?

Comment: There is not any code_number column name, neither on its table in DB nor in the domain class generated, as you can see in the code I posted. The point is that I'm applying reverse engineering, so no domain field is mapped to table name, but the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you generate the domain classes from the DB or vice versa the two have to be consistent. Because your `Documentos` domain class has a property named `codeNumber`, the `documentos` database table must have a column named `code_number`.

In your comment, you indicated that this column does not exist, so I guess this is the cause of the error.

Comment: Then I don't understand why a `codeNumber` property implies that the matched column name should be `code_number`. Is this the default behaviour in Grails? Is there any way to change this?